# Prove that connected clopen set of a topological space is a component of connectedness of this space

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Prove that connected clopen set of a topological space (X,) is a component of connectedness of this space.
Clopen set is closed and open, Connected space is a space that we cannot  represent as unition of 2 non-empty non-intersected open sets

Comment: Welcome to MSE!, What have you tried so far? write down the definition of clopen set and connected sets and tell us what you think

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be a connected subspace of $X$ which is both open and closed. Since set of  components forms partition of $X$, there is a component $C$ which contains $G$. Observe that $G\cap C$ and $(X-G) \cap C$ are open sets in $C$ and disjoint and $C$ is union of both of them. Since $C$ is connected we get a contradiction  and we conclude that $G=C$.

Edit : With respect to comment made by OP

Generally components are taken to be subspaces of topological space. A nonempty subset $Y$ of $X$ is subspace of $X$ if the topology on $Y$ consists sets of the form $Y \cap H$ where $H$ is open in $X$. So above since $G \subset C$ we have $G \cap C = G$ which is open and since $X-G$ is also open in $X$ we must have $C \cap (X-G)$ is open in $C$

Comment: why G∩C  and (X−G)∩C are open?

Comment: @Angela Devis I edited the answer